# Building dynamic number of arrays to display in Highchart

Tags: java, arrays, database-design, highcharts

I am developing a web application at the moment using Java, JS and JDBC. I have some tables with transaction details in my DB which I want to use to display in a HighChart in my JSP. I am able to get a ResultSet of the following table:

[image]

Now what I want is to split the data into a number of `ArrayList`s based on the year and category which I can pass to my HighChart - each `ArrayList` should have an object containing the year, the category and an array of monthly sales and should look like this

```
2015 , COLOUR , [1,0,0,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

2015 , DESIGN , [2,4,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

2016 , DESIGN , [0,0,0,5,5,4,7,0,0,0,0,0]

2016 , COLOUR , [0,0,0,5,5,3,6,0,0,0,0,0]
```

where the array represents the monthly sales for each year and category (0 would mean there's no sales or no data from DB for that month).

I've been trying to get this right for quite a while now, using iterators and for-loops but I cannot get it working. I am not looking for code, just some ideas and guidance on how to approach this the best way possible cause I'm a bit stuck.

Comment: Your database table/design is a mess. Is it possible to change that?

Comment: Yeah, any suggestions how? It is just a result table from a query I am making.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated Answer:

If Category is dynamic, here's what you can do:

```
create table CATEGORY (
  ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  NAME varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(ID)
)

create table MONTHS (
  MONTH int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY(MONTH)
)

create table CATEGORY_SUM (
  ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  CATEGORY int NOT NULL,
  MONTH int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(ID),
  FOREIGN KEY(CATEGORY) references CATEGORY(ID),
  FOREIGN KEY(MONTH) references MONTHS(ID)
)
```

Then fill your MONTHS table with all the months you need

Then you can do something like

```
SELECT * from CATEGORY_SUM 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN MONTHS ON CATEGORY_SUM.MONTH = MONTHS.MONTH 
order by CATEGORY_SUM.CATEGORY, CATEGORY_SUM.MONTH
```

I leave to you to get the actual name of the category into this query

Comment: The problem with it is that the categories are dynamic as well, I'm just using these as an example. I want to have a separate ArrayList for each category that the user may have created.